# Is ArcMap reading shapefile's table correctly?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile

From time to time I receive shapefiles created by hydraulic modeling software. Among other things I have to convert this info into rasters by analysing 2 important fields in the table: DEPTH2D and elevation2. The very first step in my workflow is interpolation of value stored in 2nd field.

This is how ArcMap sees table of such shapefile:

[image]

I used "DEPTH2D"= 0 query to select relevant records. Note that all of selected records have value of 1 stored in field elevation2.

This is what I see, when I use ArcView 3 (grand-grand-mother of ArcMap):

[image]

I used [Depth2d] = 0 query for selection, but [Elevation2].IsNull is also legit query and produces identical result. Second query is no go in ArcMap. Note empty cells in elevation2 field.

Finally, this is how Excel reads relevant dbf-file:

[image]

I think ArcMap fails to read 1.#QO as NoData value in numerical field and it can easily cause non-sensical results. It quietly replaces valid values (Null in this case) with something that only looks valid.

Using ArcMap how to find records with Null value in numeric field?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the dBase III+ spec is silent on conversion of invalid scientific notation to floating point values, though shapefiles do not support NULL values; the best way to define this would be "undefined behavior" (though I'd implement reading "1.#QO" in dBase as a decode error, not a `1.0` without any error). ArcView actually has no matriarchal relationship to current ArcGIS products (it's closer to being a homeless orphan of a genetic donation experiment that failed). If you want to pass NULLs, ASCII/UTF-8 text is a better bet.

Comment: I don't want to pass NULLS, Myself (and 100s of others) receive such data for further processing. Shapefiles are here to stay, because some pricey software developers decided to do so. Question is how to handle these cases. BTW unfortunate orphan outperforms mature non-relative in many areas.

Comment: File an enhancement request? Shapefile access libraries aren't likely to be augmented, but if you can make a business case... In the meantime, it's not possible to process numeric NULLs in shapefile with ArcGIS. I'd also file a bug report on the "1" parsing of the invalid SciNot value.

Comment: Handling non-existing data in dBase tables that do not support NULL is always tricky. I am not sure if these links help or add confusion https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=838752 http://www.dbase.com/KnowledgeBase/dbulletin/bu12_b.htm https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/2486.

Answer (score 1):

I "grew up" with ArcView, amazed to still see someone using it! All good explanations in the comments above and it's something you have to live with, ArcMap parsing nulls into 1. There are two options here:

1. Go back to your data supplier, explain the issue that serving out data in an archaic data format causes problems with modern GIS software. If they want to return NULL values in their data supply they need to be using a database. A file Geodatabase is the obvious choice but they could explore using geopackages too?
2. Accept the situation. A *very simple model* could automate the conversion from shapefile to file geodatabase feature class, correct the error and have a dataset ready for interpolation tool. So you create a model tool and its the first thing you run when you receive the data.

Answer (score 1):

As confirmed by @Vince 'it's not possible to process numeric NULLs in shapefile with (built-in tools) ArcGIS'.

It can be done with Python. For table:

[image]

Script:

```
import dbfread
from dbfread import DBF
table = DBF(r'f:\SCRATCH\abc.dbf')
for record in table:
    print record
```

Outputs:

```
OrderedDict([(u'ELEMENT_NO', 0), (u'DEPTH2D', 1.352), (u'ELEVATION2', 45.461)])
OrderedDict([(u'ELEMENT_NO', 1), (u'DEPTH2D', 1.423), (u'ELEVATION2', 45.532)])
OrderedDict([(u'ELEMENT_NO', 2), (u'DEPTH2D', 0.25), (u'ELEVATION2', 45.438)])
OrderedDict([(u'ELEMENT_NO', 3), (u'DEPTH2D', 0.0), (u'ELEVATION2', None)])
OrderedDict([(u'ELEMENT_NO', 4), (u'DEPTH2D', 0.512), (u'ELEVATION2', 45.91)])
```

So 'dbfread' module correctly identifies Nulls.